# Prove that $\dfrac{nm^2-n+1}{2mn-2n+1} \notin\mathbb{Z}$ when $m \geq 2$

Tags: real-numbers, integers

Given: $n$ and $m$ are positive integers with
$m≥2$, show that:

$$\frac {nm²-n+1}{2mn - 2n+1}\notin \mathbb Z$$

My attempt:

$n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$

$nm^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

$nm^2 - n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$2mn - 2n \in \mathbb{Z}$

So $\dfrac{nm^2 - n }{2mn - 2n+1}$ may or may not $\in \mathbb{Z}$

But $\dfrac{1}{2mn - 2n + 1} \in \mathbb{Z}$ only when

$$
\begin{aligned}
2mn - 2n +1&= 1 \\
2mn&= 2n \\
m&= 1
\end{aligned}
$$
Given $m \geq 2$, $\dfrac{1}{2mn - 2n + c} \notin \mathbb{Z}$

So $\dfrac{nm^2 - n + 1}{2mn - 2n+1} \notin \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts

Comment: @lulu The OP just included an image showing he/she has worked... Unfortunately it is almost unreadable !

Comment: @JeanMarie  Well...that calculation doesn't make a lot of sense (and it's hard to read, as you remark).  In it, the OP appears to imagine that the only way this fraction could be an integer is if $\frac 1{2mn-2n+1}$ were an integer, though of course a priori there are other cases to worry about.

Comment: Can you please guide me a little to prove that the above exp. Isn't an integer?

Comment: @arnavJha I have edited your question to include your efforts to avoid the question being closed. However, I was not always able to tell what you had written, so you should edit to fix any typos in my reproduction of your solution.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Thank you so much for editing my question! There were no errors btw.

Comment: One thing you can try is to set $p:=\frac {nm^2-n+1}{2mn - 2n+1}$ and assume that $p$ is an integer and show that the cubic "diophantine" equation $p(2mn - 2n+1)=nm^2-n+1$ hasn't integer solutions $(m,n,p)$.

Comment: You have to assume $n\ne 0$... otherwise any value of $m$ provides an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If $\frac{2nm^2-2n+2}{2mn-2n+1}$ is not an integer, then the original fraction $\frac{nm^2-n+1}{2mn-2n+1}$ cannot be an integer either. So we show that $\frac{2nm^2-2n+2}{2mn-2n+1}$ is not an integer.
\begin{align*}
\frac{2nm^2-2n+2}{2mn-2n+1} &= m + \frac{2mn-2n-m+2}{2mn-2n+1} \\[6pt]
&=m + 1 + \frac{1-m}{2mn-2n+1} \\[6pt] &= m+1 - \frac{m-1}{2n(m-1)+1}.
\end{align*}
As $m+1$ is an integer, it is sufficient to show that the last term $\frac{m-1}{2n(m-1)+1}$ is not an integer.
Indeed, since $n>0$ and $m\geq 2$, we have
$$ 0<\frac{m-1}{2n(m-1)+1} \leq \frac{m-1}{2(m-1)+1}< \frac{m-1}{2(m-1)}=\frac{1}{2}$$
so $\frac{m-1}{2n(m-1)+1}\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and in particular not an integer, as desired.

Comment: I don't understand only one point: why can you assume $n\ge 2$ ?

Comment: It seems that the last fraction should be $\frac{1-m}{2n(m-1)+1}$ and not $\frac{1+m}{2m(n-1)+1}$

Comment: I'm sorry I misread $n \ge 2$ as well. But for $n=1$ the fraction becomes $\frac{m^2}{2m-1}$, and one can show that $\frac{2m^2}{2m-1}$ $=$ $m - \frac{1}{2m-1}$ cannot be integral.

Comment: @Mike Still, in the second row of your calculation in the middle, the numerator should be $1-m$ and not $1+m$ (in particular it may not be positive as you claim).

Comment: I apologize for the arithmetic errors. I actually had also misread and mistook it as $m,n \ge 2$ instead of just $m \ge 2$. Anyways I corrected. The crux of the typo is $2mn-2n+1 = 2n(m-1)+1$, instead of $2m(n-1)+1$, as I had written

Comment: @Tommy1234 noted thanks and corrected

Comment: Thank you @Tommy1234 for the edits, looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for contradiction that $$\frac{nm^2-n+1}{2nm-2n+1}=\frac{n(m-1)(m+1)+1}{2n(m-1)+1}$$ is some integer — say, $k+1$.  Then $$n(m-1)(m+1)+1=n(m-1)\cdot2(k+1)+k+1$$  Rearranging, $$n(m-1)(m-2k-1)=k$$  To make things pretty, I will let $l=m-1$; then $$nl(l-2k)=k\tag{1}$$

Set $a=l-2k$; then $k=nla$.  Rewriting (1) in terms of $a$, $$a=l-2k=l-2nla=l(1-2na)$$  Likewise, let $b=1-2na$; then $a=lb$, so that $$b=1-2na=1-2nlb$$  But now we can rearrange and notice that $$(1+2nl)b=1$$  Since this is an equation in integers, there are only two solutions: $$(b,1+2nl)\in\{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$$  Since $nl>0$, neither case is possible, our desired contradiction.